# Aplicacion se cierra y da error cuando vuelve de segundo plano

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Seré lo mas especifico.
Mi aplicacion empieza con una splash_screen donde se conecta a firebase y verifica un valor. Luego pasa a mainActivity y se finaliza (finish).
Dentro de la splash_screen defino `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true)` para tener los datos offline.

La aplicacion funciona bien salvo cuando pasa a segundo plano. Al volver a la misma, queda unos segundos la pantalla en blanco y se cierra repentinamente. No pone ningun tipo de error.
En crashlytics aparece este error:

***ERROR:***

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.guiacampings/com.app.guiacampings.Splash_Screen_Activity}: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Calls to setPersistenceEnabled() must be made before any other usage of FirebaseDatabase instance.
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3556)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3703)
       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2216)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

alguien puede decirme donde puede estar el problema? En mainActivity vuelvo a usar firebase database.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37753991/com-google-firebase-database-databaseexception-calls-to-setpersistenceenabled/46005514

Answer (score 0):

El problema se indica aquí:

> Calls to setPersistenceEnabled() must be made before any other usage
> of FirebaseDatabase instance.

Debes primeramente inicializar `Firebase`, para esto crea una clase que extienda de `Application`, donde se habilite la persistencia:

```
public class FirebaseApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);   
    }
}
```

Dentro de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` define esta clase en `application`:

```
 <application
    android:name=".FirebaseApp"
    ...
    ...
    ...>
```

Comment: Esa solucion ya la encontre en otro posteo. Gracias igualmente.